# How to change cygdrive to windows directory structure

Tags: linux, bash, shell, batch-file, cygwin

How can I change a `cygdrive` to a `windows directory structure`.
For example :
I have :

> /cygdrive/c/fighter/library/binaries

how can I change this to

> c:/fighter/library/binaries

either using a batch script or using a bash (.sh) script

I would be grateful for any sort of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try cygpath -w, e.g.

```
$ cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/Users
C:\Users
```

Comment: it gives me -w command not found, I did , `A=cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/Users`  `echo $A`

Comment: What happens when you just run "cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/Users", Does it return "C:\Users"? If it does then you have the tools. Looks like you are trying to save the result to a variable A, in which case you should do "A=$(cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/Users)".